# Why am I unable to access "System.DirectoryServices" from any namespace but my presentation layer?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I am accessing active directory with the `System.DirectoryServices` library, currently in my web layer.  However, I'm trying to move a function from a code-behind file to a VB class in another namespace, and I cannot seem to access that class from within that namespace.  What gives?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the class you're trying to move the logic to is inside of another project?

If this is the case you need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices` assembly on that project.

Comment: Duh.  Early morning, apparently.  Thanks!